# How to match tokens with a dictionary key and get corresponding value

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, text-mining, topic-modeling

I have a dataframe with tokens like below and i want to match with keys of a dictionary and get corresponding key and value.

Dataframe:

```
    A                     B
    1          ['i','like','apples', 'banana' ,'lot','however','do','not','eat','them','but' , 'sandwich'  , 'also' , 'good']
    2          ['avengers','series','something','like','most','annabelle','movies' , 'cannot' ,'watch' , 'night' , 'time']
    3          ['virat kohli','batsmen','world','like','most','federer','nadal' ,'tennis']
```

I have a dictionary like below:

```
 key          value
apple         fruit
banana        fruit
grapes        fruit
sandwich      junkfood
noodles       junkfood
avengers      action
deadpool      action
annabelle     horror
virat kohli   cricket
federer       tennis
nadal         tennis
timo ball     table tennis
```

I want to match all the tokens of a row with keys of dictionary and get matched keys and value like below.

output:

```
A              B                                     C
1       [fruit , junk food]           ['apple' , 'banana' , 'sandwich']
2       ['action' , 'horror']         ['avengers' , 'annabelle']
3       ['cricket' , 'tennis']        ['virat kohli' ,'nadal' , 'federer']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to match the strings with the dictionary but i'm getting the value error and not able to resolve them as i 'm new to programming

Comment: hope if you can provide the solution that would help me to my own learning

Comment: Show us some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along with list comprehension,

```
#if 'df' is  your data frame  & 'dct_' is your dictionary
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda lst: [item for item in lst if item in dct_.keys()])
df['D'] = df['B'].apply(lambda lst: [dct_.get(item) for item in lst if item in dct_.keys()])
```

```
  A              B                                        C                          D
0  1  [i, like, apples, banana,...]               [ banana, sandwich]          [fruit, junkfood]
1  2  [avengers, series, something,...]         [avengers, annabelle]           [action, horror]    
2  3  [virat kohli, batsmen,...]        [virat kohli, federer, nadal]  [cricket, tennis, tennis]
```

Comment: Thanks for the respone shijith ,The above code works really well however i have small concern related to D column , i don't want to have duplicates like in 3rd row , tennis shown multiple times.is there any possibility to remove the duplicates from it

Comment: use `set()` to get only unique values, if you want to return a list use `list(set())`i.e. `lambda lst: set([dct_.get(item) for item in lst if item in dct_.keys()])`

Comment: I tried it but i'm facing Typerror:unhashable type : numpy.ndarray  for the above line of code in the comment

Comment: use `list(set())` instead `lambda lst: list(set([dct_.get(item) for item in lst if item in dct_.keys()]))`

Comment: the error remains same when i use above line of code

Comment: what is the `type()` of your data frame?, the above code will work in `pandas data frame`

Comment: i have pandas dataframe  and i'm applying the above lambda function on a pandas series like df['D'] = df['B'].apply(lambda lst: list(set([dct_.get(item) for item in lst if item in dct_.keys()])))